# Copy from one and convert to another Attribute in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my App i use a Core Data model with only one Entity and some Attributes in it. What I want to achieve:

Attribute A "imagePath" is of type NSString that stores the path to the Document Directory where the corresponding .png image is.

Attribute B "imageCoreData" is of type Binary Data.

I want to move all the images in Document Directory to Core Data.

So I need code that does the following - get the image from Attribute A in Document Directory, convert it to NSData and save it as Binary Data to Attribute B "imageCoreData". And does this for every object i got.

Also it would be great if I could get informed if it´s successfully completed. Maybe also it should work in background to not block the UI.

The same I want for:

Attribute C "date" of type NSDate that stores a date.

Attribute D "dateString" of type NSString.

Get the date from Attribute C and convert the date from NSDate to NSString and save it in Attribute D. I need this also for all objects I got.

**UPDATE**

I can get a dictionary with all my paths to Document Directory. But how to pull out all images, covert and save to Attribute B ?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSEntityDescription *entityImg = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;


fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entityImg propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"imagePath"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;


NSArray *dictionary = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly nothing really working. The Convertion from one Attribute type to another isn´t that hard, but I fail in doing it for all my objects I got at once. I guess I need to loop through all my objects somehow, but since I am beginner I couldn t achieve this.

Comment: Look into NSFetchRequest to see how to retrieve all your entities from your Core Data store. Once you have retrieved them, you can iterate over them, update the attributes, and then save your updates.

Comment: Probably the problem is `NSArray *dictionary`. Something strange with that line?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is non-sensical to store the same information twice. Decide which format you want, and store that.

Second, it is not recommended to store large images as binary data in Core Data. You could store small images, such as thumbnails, but otherwise it is a bad idea.

Third, when fetching your entity, you do not have to go into he complications of `NSDictionaryResultType`. Just use the default (`NSManagedObjectResultType`) and work with that. Because of the *faulting* mechanism of Core Data you will not have to pay any significant price in terms of memory or performance.

Guessing what your original problem was, you perhaps want to send the data somewhere else. In this case you should make the necessary transformations *ad hoc*.

For example, to create a date string from your entity, subclass the `NSManagedObject` (I would call this class `Image`) and add a convenience method. (Note that the date format is just an example. Consult the `NSDateFormatter` documentation for what you need.)

```
-(NSString*)dateString {
    if (!self.date) { return @""; }
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (!formatter) {
         formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"; 
    }
    return [formatter stringFromDate:self.date];
}
```

As for the image, you do not have to do any conversion because the content of your png file is already of type `NSData`. Just read it from the file URL and use the `NSData` object.

Comment: Thanks for help. My problem is not really the converting. I do not know how I can write a method that copies the coresponding image from the doc dir for each object and saves it to binary data attribute in core data. I can not iterate through all objects and do this for each object the right inage. And do this all at once.

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. You still want to do what I stated was a bad idea, well, OK. Fetch all object, loop through them, retrieve the image, store it in the object, save at the end. What is the problem?

Comment: The code for that ;) I don t kniw how to do that loop through and do it for each object at once

Comment: If you cannot write an Objective-C loop you are way over your head with Core Data. Try some tutorials first. Good luck!